# update on change by ajax in yii gridview

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, cgridview

I've got a simple table tbl_task in my database with the followings attributes:

- id int auto_increment
- description varchar
- complete boolean

Now I created a gridview. the value of the complete attribute is shown by a checkbox. There should be the possibility to change the value of the complete attribute. If you do that, it should save the changes in the database. Meanwhile the gridview gets every 3 seconds the newest records from the database.

I've tried to adapt the gridview js file but it doesn't work.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve my problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be very difficult to accomplish.

1) In order to update the grid every 3 seconds, use javascript setInterval and call the grid's update method:

```
jQuery('#grid_id_here').yiiGridView('update');
```

2) In the complete column, set it to `"type" => "raw"` and then you put as `"value"` something like `"<input type='checkbox' onclick='mark_complete('.$data->id.')'>"`

3) Define a javascript function that completes the task

```
function mark_complete(id) {
// 1. make here a ajax call that updates the task's complete field
// 2. on the success of that ajax call place again the update command to update the grid
}
```

Comment: thanks. i've made it with the selectionchanged property and called an javascript function